# NAME("name", true), what does true do here?

Tags: java

```
public enum Properties
{
    NAME("name", true) ,
    CATEGORY("category",false);

    ...
}
```

I have a enum like this.
And it is used like this:

```
myMap.put(Properties.NAME, name);
```

My question is, seems I am using the `"name"` from `NAME`?
What does that `boolean` value do here?   `"NAME("name", true) ,"`

Thanks

Edited:

But my question is when I use it like this `"Properties.NAME"` I am getting `"name"`, how can I actually get that `"true"`?

Comment: A `boolean` value is being passed to the `enum` constructor. It is not possible to say what it is for without more information.

Comment: but my question is ,when I use it like this "Properties.NAME" I am getting "name", how can I actually get that "true"?

Comment: No. `Properties.NAME` is just one of the enum constants. It is an instance of `Properties`, not `String`. I don't know how to get the `boolean`. There may be a getter in the enum. I have no idea.

Comment: It may be their just for internal purposes, for instance for the `toString()` whether it should be capitalized. Or there might be a method in the enum for retrieving that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of your enum has two parameters: a String and a boolean. For example:

```java
public enum Properties
{
    NAME("name", true),
    CATEGORY("category", false);

    private final String s;
    private final boolean b;

    private Properties(String s, boolean b) {
        this.s = s;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public boolean getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Now, `Properties.NAME.getS()` returns `"name"` and `Properties.NAME.getB()` returns `true`.

`Properties.NAME` returns the object `NAME` of your enum `Properties`, and when you use it as a `String`, it will call the method `toString()` (like all objects in Java). And `toString()` call `name()` which returns the name of the object. Here `"NAME"`.